# Array of class objects foreach in smarty

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I am working on a PHP project where I have an array of objects. I want to pass this array of objects to a Smarty template that can loop round and get the information out of the structure.

An example output of the object array is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => FilesAndDirectories Object
        (
            [parent] => 
            [directory] => /
            [files] => Array
                (
                    [0] => FileInformation Object
                        (
                            [fileName] => test_wav.wav
                            [modifiedTime] => 2014-09-11T19:20:20.000Z
                            [fieSize] => 22332
                        )

                    [1] => FileInformation Object
                        (
                            [fileName] => record_message_from_sip:300@sip-0-2-0.aculab.com.wav
                            [modifiedTime] => 2014-09-11T21:01:39.000Z
                            [fieSize] => 36036
                        )

                    [2] => FileInformation Object
                        (
                            [fileName] => record_message_from_sip:44123456789@sip-0-2-0.aculab.com.wav
                            [modifiedTime] => 2014-09-11T21:07:05.000Z
                            [fieSize] => 29796
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => FilesAndDirectories Object
        (
            [parent] => /
            [directory] => my_directory_test
            [files] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => FilesAndDirectories Object
        (
            [parent] => my_directory_test
            [directory] => dir
            [files] => Array
                (
                    [0] => FileInformation Object
                        (
                            [fileName] => /record_message_from_sip:300@sip-0-2-0.aculab.com.wav
                            [modifiedTime] => 2014-09-12T20:36:05.000Z
                            [fieSize] => 44596
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Below is how I am getting the above output stored

```
$fileManager = new FileManager();
$result = $fileManager->getFileListing();
```

$result will now contain the above structure.

I am then passing $result to assign to a smarty variable as follows:

```
$smarty = new Smarty();
        $smarty->setTemplateDir("templates");

        $smarty->assign("fileListing", $result);
        echo $smarty->fetch("directoryListing.tpl");
```

The smarty template file looks like the following:

```
<table>
    {foreach $fileListing as $directory}
        <tr>

        </tr>
    {/foreach}
</table>
```

The problem I am having is that I get an exception thrown via Smarty which is

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class FilesAndDirectories could not
>   be converted to string in

Comment: Is there something between `<tr>` in template? What is in line thrown by exception?

Comment: No there's not at the moment. The exception is thrown on the line ``$smarty->assign("fileListing", $result);``

Comment: Could you try use method `assign_by_ref()` instead of `assign()` or check one of the presented [here](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/advanced.features.tpl) examples?

Comment: @marian0 thanks this was what I needed. Could you make it an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `assign_by_ref()` instead of `assign()` or check one of the presented [here](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/advanced.features.tpl) examples.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your $result variable. Try doing a print_r($result) and see what you get. You can only explicitly pass name/value pairs, or associative arrays containing the name/value pairs. If your $result var doesn't fit that structure it would throw an error.